# Sharepoint 2013 Modal Dialog title

Tags: 2013, modal-dialog

I'm using SharePoint 2013

When I open view/edit item in a list the modal window displays the '`list title`' and the '`item title`' at the top of the window

Is there a way to change the '`item title`' in the modal window to display the result of a column related to the selected list item (ie., '`DivisionTrackingNumber`')

Resulting in the following modal window title:

> 'LIST NAME' - '15-000205'

Comment: Are you opening the modal using JavaScript?

Comment: no i am using the edit/view on the list toolbar or the title link in a webpart

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way for achieving this.

One option that comes to my mind is using jQuery. You can edit the Form page and add below script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var newTitle = jQuery('#SPFieldId').html();
    newTitle = 'List Title - ' + newTitle;
    jQuery('#dialogTitleSpan').html(newTitle);
});
```

You can find `SPFieldId` using browser developer tool

Comment: I added the following to the default display page:<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var newTitle = jQuery('8ae4cc33-d91b-4421-b8e7-d5c07e446570').html();
    newTitle = 'List Title - ' + newTitle;
    jQuery('#dialogTitleSpan').html(newTitle);
    });
   </script>

Comment: Not working for me.  I can only add script to the main area of a page and not the header or footer.  I also tried in CEWP with no success.  I get a webpart error when script is added directly to the page.  Do i need a $ instead of JQuery? any suggestions?

Comment: Put alert statements and make sure code is executing, and title is read properly.

Comment: Getting undefined for new title (List Title - undefined).  Its not retrieving the data from the field ID. Getting (object Object) on #dialogTitleSpan line. Could it be the CDN? Using the MS one.  Any further assistance would be greatly appreciated.